# XML and PHP questions

Tags: php

```
$new = $doc->createElement("Cars");
```

to open an element how would I close this element?

and if i have a text box

```
<input type="text" name="toCity">
```

how can i write what the user puts in the textbox as an element?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$new = $doc->createElement("Cars");
```

don't create just an open tag but the whole element. This means that if you don't append elements to Cars, it will be an **empty tag** which is like:

```
<cars />
```

otherwise, you can append elements using the [appendChild()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) method and it will look like:

```
<cars>
   // other elements here
</cars>
```

Anyway to add a text in a textarea you can use this code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput=true;
$textarea = $doc->createElement("textarea");
$text = $doc->createTextNode("The text I like");
$textarea->appendChild($text);
$doc->appendChild($textarea);
```

Comment: ty and how would i append an element to it

Comment: `code`
<?php
$doc = new DOMDoucment();
$doc->formatOutput=true;
$new = $doc->createElement("Employees");
$doc->appendChild( $new ); \
$b = $doc->createElement( "employee");
$doc->save("wrote.xml") 
?>
`code`

whats wrong with that code:S

Comment: @suffix If I understood your need, this should be the right code: http://pastebin.com/JXBmPREW

Comment: ok sir and the second part? getting the users input and adding to xml element?

Comment: Sir i wanted the infromation FROM the text box not write to it:p

Comment: @suffix Well, in this case, this is a totally different question and you should open another question. A little tip is that you need a form ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4940/discussion-between-suffix-and-aurelio-de-rosa)